# Lodash LowerCase Space Issue

Tags: lodash

I am using lodash to turn a string in the lowercase letter. It works fine when I all the letters in the string is uppercase. It turns them into lower case but as soon I put a lower case alphabet in it, spaces appear in between the string out of nowhere. How can I remove these spaces?

Input:

```
var string= lodash.lowerCase("rRRRR-R")
console.log(string);
```

Output :
r rrrr r

One the spaces is because of the hyphen. The one in the beginning I do not understand. I can not use lodash.toLower because I need a space whenever there is a hypen. I can not get it with the loadash.toLower command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `lodash.replace` method to replace the hyphen with a space and then use `lodash.toLower` to convert the string to lowercase.

```
var string = _.toLower(_.replace("rRRRR-R", "-", " "));
console.log(string);
```

```
O/P : r rrrr r
```